# How to use two custom list views on one activity in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to show two custom listviews on one activity. I use following XML code.

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<ListView android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Source Code:

```
ListView list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
ListView list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
```

but the list view is not populated.
        i am new in android. please help me
        Thanks

Comment: Which `ListView` isn't populated, `list1`, `list2`, or both? In either case, you'll need to post the code where you try to populate your list(s).

Answer (score 0):

Hello my friend first rule never ever place two list views it will mess because of scrolling.
Maybe you want to use a scrollview and inflate two layouts on it :D